# What is "Camelot" from War of the Worlds?

Tags: war-of-the-worlds

What is the scene comprised of? All I can find are crappy reconstructions on YouTube and I'd just like a rundown of what the scene is.

[image: Screenshot of previz]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is [a deleted scene from the film](https://fromdirectorstevenspielberg.tumblr.com/post/105795976220/there-are-a-number-of-scenes-in-war-of-the-worlds).

> This sequence was due to take place towards the end of the film, shortly after the ferry scene, and saw Ray, Robbie and Rachel encountering a battalion of tripods in a deserted neighbourhood. The trio can only look on as people are pulled out of their homes by the Tripods tentacles.

The name apparently comes from the name of [the neighborhood where that action happens](https://www.camelotcohousing.com/).

The scene is mildly notorious in that it was filmed, and all VFX was done for it, but it has not appeared on any releases as a deleted scene, so all fans have are pre-viz, behind-the-scenes photos, and one still from the final VFX.

Comment: If it is a deserted neighborhood, why are there people being pulled out of their homes? I guess the streets are deserted. Sloppy wording by Spielberg.

Comment: @JonCuster the blog isn’t written by Spielberg — it’s just about his works